# Reading data from multiple files and writing the data to a new file giving unexpected result?

Tags: java, android, filewriter

I've split a mp3 file of 10 MB size into 10 parts of 1 MB each in mp3 format on my Android device, each file plays successfully by the player but while reading the data of all the 10 files and writing it to a single file the total size of the new file is more than 17 MB and the file doesn't play itself. Following is the code:

**CODE FOR FILE SPLIT :**

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/MusicFile.mp3");
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        int size = 1048576; // 1 MB of data
        byte buffer[] = new byte[size];

        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            i = fis.read(buffer, 0, size);
            if (i == -1) {
                break;
            }

        File filename = getSplitFileName("split_" + count);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        fos.write(buffer, 0, i);
        ++count;
        }
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**CODE FOR FILE JOIN :**

```
File folder = new File(cacheDirSplit.getAbsolutePath());
File files[] = folder.listFiles();

BufferedReader bufReader = null;
BufferedWriter bufWriter = null;

    if (files.length > 1) {
        try {
            File fileName = getJoinedFileName("NewMusicFile");
            String data;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                long dataSize = 0;
                bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                                files[i]));
                bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                                fileName, true));
            while ((data = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                bufWriter.write(data);
                dataSize = dataSize + data.getBytes().length;
                }
            Log.i("TAG", "File : " + files[i] + "size ==> "
                                + dataSize);
            }
            bufReader.close();
            bufWriter.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What i do not understand is that while reading each file is read as 1.7MB as printed by the LOGCAT output but on the device when i check the splitted file is of 1MB only. Is there anything wrong with the code or is there some other thing I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you split the file can you also share that code? You said you can play the splitted files individually which you shouldn't be because the files except the first file should not contain the mp3 file header. So I suspect all of your splitted files contains header information which explains the grow in the file size.

Comment: That your splitting code works... i does not have to be equal to size if you do a read. You should check that. Do all parts really play? Unbelievable. What kind of forgiving player is that?

Comment: @greenapps The default music player that android provides

Comment: You create a new BufferedWriter for every file you add. That's not ok. Just use one. Create one at start. Outside the loop.

Comment: @greenapps it is ok since it is appending to the previous file. Take a look at the constructor http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html FileWriter(java.lang.String, boolean)

Comment: Second thought, maybe there was an other file the time you tried to marge the files again and you append on it so this might be the case.

Comment: @Onur I didn't get u mate?

Comment: I mean, think that there was a 7mb there when you want to join the files again, since you don't check for an old file, you might have been append on that file.

Comment: @Onur Nup, I'm writing the file in a new folder on my SD Card and i delete the file before doing the join operation.

Comment: Even if you think it is ok you better dont do it. The logic to do it is missing. Your code becomes difficult to read also because it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `readLine()` on the content of an mp3 file. `readLine()` is for text files only. And if the ten were really playable and real mp3 files you had to strip the header first as Onur explained.

Comment: Any format is saved on the device as a file only so i think `readline()` should work, but if not then can u suggest how the above can be achieved?

Comment: Well writing you use write() thats ok. You do not use writeLine() because that would be wrong. Use read() instead of readLine(). While splitting you used read() already so why do you have to ask now?

Comment: Can you suggest how to use `read()` with `FileWriter`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean with FileReader? By the way: i prefer thanks afterwards.

Comment: Oops! Yes `FileReader`

Comment: I suggest you use FileInput/OutputStream as you did while splitting.